Release + replace wires in pcb connection block: on Ritto 7230 intercom phone
I have to move my house/gate Ritto 7230 intercom phone.
The connection block doesn't have any obvious release mechanism for the wires: none of the holes on the front seem to offer any possibilities.
I took the block off the board, but the underneath is quite smooth.
Is a special tool of some sort required?


Insert a needle in the tiny hole?

They don't exactly give these devices away free with the cornflakes, so I'm not inclined to experiment too much.

Then buy the official extraction tool?


Get a needle-like tool
Insert in the hole above the red wire (closest to the 'a' legend)
Press in
Pull out the red wire
Repeat with the black wire.


To whoever closed this question: apologies, I hadn't realised the site was design-specific. However, I do think it would have been polite to have pointed me at somewhere more suitable, rather than just kicking me out on my arse.

Thank you, Davide Andrea, for your input. Are you referring to the round hole next to the red wire, or the rectangular one? If the latter, that's not a hole. I believe it's a moulding mark from where the metal innards were initially inserted.

@SamDon: round. "pointed me at somewhere more suitable". Unfortunately, there is no stack exchange more suitable to your question than this one. There are other forums that would be suitable, but I think it would be in bad form for me to direct you to a web site outside the stack exchange network.


round: Thank you! I shall dig out a mag. glass and give it a go.


bad form: I beg to differ. What you're saying is: "We can't help you, but we won't tell you who can". That seems rather a churlish attitude to me.

